# Submit form input array with jquery ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input, multidimensional-array

Alright I want to submit a form thru jquery ajax. All the inputs are in an array and it is multidimensional.

Its a dynamic form that uses the array key as the question id. 
The subkey is used for grouping the questions at a question set.

```
<form name="testing" id="testing" method="post">
    <label>Question 1?</label> 
    <input type="text" name="data[14][1]" id="" class="" value=""><br>
    <label>Question 2?</label> 
    <input type="text" name="data[16][1]" id="" class="" value=""><br>
    <label>Question 1?</label> 
    <input type="text" name="data[14][2]" id="" class="" value=""><br>
    <label>Question 2?</label> 
    <input type="text" name="data[16][2]" id="" class="" value=""><br>
    <label>Question 3?</label> 
    <select name="data[19]" id="" class="">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So that is my example html. Here is my example jquery:

```
$("#testing").submit(function() { 
           var data = $('input[name^="data\\["]').serializeArray();
                $.ajax({ 
                 type: "POST",
                 url:  "upload.php",
                 data: {internalform: "submit", data: data},
                 dataType : "text",

           success: function(returndata){
            if(returndata == "no") 
             { return false;
             } else {
               alert("clicked 1 " + returndata);
                }
                 } 
                 });    
            return false;
            });
```

Problem is I get this as a return array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => data[14]
            [value] => sd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => data[16]
            [value] => s
        )

)
```

But I want an array like this:

```
Array ( [14] => ddd [16] => ddd [19] => 4 )
```

Im sure its simple but I'm missing something. I know why its doing it but I can't get it the way I want it/need it. Can someone help?

Comment: When you say returnarray do you mean that `returnData` or something else?

Comment: All the answers I've seen for this same problem are workarounds, but they don't address the fundamental issue - why doesn't `serializeArray` properly parse brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below snippet,I have not tested this but probably it should work.

Replace `var data = $('input[name^="data\\["]').serializeArray();` part with below snippet

```
var data = {};
$.each($('input[name^="data\\["]')​.serializeArray()​, function() {
    data[this.name] = this.value;
})​;
```

Try this it will solve the data coming in front issues

i have worked out this one

```
var data = {};
$.each($('select[name^="data\\["] , input[name^="data\\["]').serializeArray(), function() {
   var vv = this.name.replace(/data/, '' ).replace(/(\[[0-9]\])$/,'');
   data[vv] = this.value;           
});
```

Comment: Its close. I get this as a response.

(
    [data[14] => ssssss
    [data[16] => ss
)

Two issues with that. 
1. the [ in front of data isn't suppose to be there.
2. the select input isn't getting posted.

Almost there though.

Comment: Thanks, I messed around with it and I made it work with this:

var data = {};
            $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function() {
                
                data[this.name] = this.value;
            });

That did what I wanted and I removed the data part from the name in the form so the form name is only the question id

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in jquery but you can transform that array in php

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
   $index = intval(preg_replace("/data\[([0-9]*)\]/", '\1' $item['name']));
   $result[$index] = $item['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = {}; 
$('input[name^="data\\["]').serializeArray().map(function(n){
    var name = n['name'].replace(/data\[([0-9]*)\]\[(.*)\]/, '$1');
    data[name] = n['value'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {};
$.each($('input[name^="data\\["]')​.serializeArray()​, function() {
    data[this.name] = this.value;
})​;
```

gives console error >>

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list