# Convert Multidimentional Input arry to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I want to grab my Input fields **value** and put them into a JSON string Ultimately (through Jquery/Javascript).

This is my html markup

```
<input type="text" class="specifications" name="specifications[0][title]" />
<input type="text" class="specifications" name="specifications[0][stat]" />

<input type="text" class="specifications" name="specifications[1][title]" />
<input type="text" class="specifications" name="specifications[1][stat]" />

<input type="text" class="specifications" name="specifications[2][title]" />
<input type="text" class="specifications" name="specifications[2][stat]" />

<input type="text" class="specifications" name="specifications[3][title]" />
<input type="text" class="specifications" name="specifications[3][stat]" />
```

I want my JSON string to be something like this

```
[
{ title: 'title1', stat: '1000' },
{ title: 'title1', stat: '2000' },
{ title: 'title2', stat: '3000' },
{ title: 'title3', stat: '4000' },
{ title: 'title4', stat: '5000' }
]
```

I've searched a lot now and found these threads but they doesn't help me all the way with what i want to accomplish

[jquery serialize input with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127227/jquery-serialize-input-with-arrays)

[Submit form input array with jquery ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474658/submit-form-input-array-with-jquery-ajax-post)

Please help.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object.

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the object (or JSON string) afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create the object you've described from the inputs you have:

```
    var specsLen = $('input.specifications').length / 2,
        array = [],
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < specsLen; i += 1) {
        array.push({
            title: $('input.specifications[name="specifications[' + i + '][title]"]').val(),
            stat: $('input.specifications[name="specifications[' + i + '][stat]"]').val()
        });
    })
```

[See fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/D4EaY/)